# How do I find out what options git-diff uses when it invokes less?

Tags: git, bash, shell, unix, git-diff

I want to reproduce the pager behavior that git-diff uses but I don't know how. Is there a way I could find out what options it uses with less?

I already tried this: `strings "$(dirname $(which git-diff))/*" | grep 'less '`

And this (while less was running): `ps aux | grep less` <= Didn't show me which options it was using.

I'm on Darwin.

Comment: What behavior are you trying to replicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the `git-config` man page, specifically the description of `core.pager`.  Also, you could inspect the environment of the pager process

```
$ tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/5568/environ | grep LESS
LESS=FRSX
```

Comment: /proc doesn't exist on Darwin but you were right about it being in man git-config.

Comment: Great pointer. Just to clarify from the doc the command line run from git is `LESS=FRSX less -+FRSX -FRX`

Answer (score 3):

A useful technique for doing this sort of thing is to set the `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` environment variable to a shell script that does nothing but echo its arguments. Then run `git diff` and look at the output.

Comment: good call. Also echo the LESS environment varable from this script in case it's also used

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your .bashrc:

```
export LESS="$LESS -S" # add more options to `less`
```

Comment: On ubuntu at least this enables ctrl-c, a good thing, but kills the colored output and introduces unreadable escape codes rendering it useless

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/idiff for portable ways to control less